# For iterator to delete items in array

Tags: java

I wrote this little method to delete all items in a array with a specific value:

```
   public void removeNote2(String r){
         for(String file : notes){
             if(file == r){
                 notes.remove(r);
             }
         }
    }
```

Somehow i always get this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at Notebook.removeNote2(Notebook.java:63)
```

What did i wrong? And what do i have to change?

Comment: First `if(file == r)` is not good. Use equals to compare content of Strings. Second google for `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You are removing while iterating.  Using Iterator.remove() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot iterate the list and remove items from it the way you're trying to do. It leads to `ConcurrentModificationException`. The proper way to do this, is to use iterator:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = notes.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  String file = iterator.next();
  if (file == r)
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Btw, you'll probably want to use `equals()` when comparing strings, not `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, do this:

```
notes.removeIf(file -> file.equals(r));
```